# Running Reddit - Paster Shell errors re: webhelpers.rails deprecated

Tags: reddit

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-02:/reddit/r2$ paster serve --reload example.ini http_port=8080Starting subprocess with file monitor
    /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Pylons-0.9.6.2-py2.6.egg/pylons/middleware.py:11: DeprecationWarning: The webhelpers.rails package is deprecated.
    - Please begin migrating to the new helpers in webhelpers.html,
      webhelpers.text, webhelpers.number, etc.  
    - Import url_for() directly from routes, and redirect_to() from
      pylons.controllers.util (if using Pylons) or from routes.
    - All Javascript support has been deprecated.  You can write link_to_remote()
      yourself or use one of the third-party Javascript libraries.
      from webhelpers.rails.asset_tag import javascript_path
    /reddit/r2/r2/lib/manager/tp_manager.py:22: DeprecationWarning: the sha module is deprecated; use the hashlib module instead
      import pylons, sha
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/paster", line 8, in <module>
        load_entry_point('PasteScript==1.7.3', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.6.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 84, in run
        invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.6.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 123, in invoke
        exit_code = runner.run(args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.6.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 218, in run
        result = self.command()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.6.egg/paste/script/serve.py", line 276, in command
        relative_to=base, global_conf=vars)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.6.egg/paste/script/serve.py", line 313, in loadapp
        **kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.4-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 203, in loadapp
        return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.4-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 224, in loadobj
        return context.create()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.4-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 617, in create
        return self.object_type.invoke(self)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.4-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 109, in invoke
        return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.4-py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/util/fixtypeerror.py", line 57, in fix_call
        val = callable(*args, **kw)
      File "/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py", line 558, in make_app
        load_environment(global_conf, app_conf)
      File "/reddit/r2/r2/config/environment.py", line 54, in load_environment
        config['pylons.g'] = app_globals.Globals(global_conf, app_conf, paths)
      File "/reddit/r2/r2/lib/app_globals.py", line 173, in __init__
        self.memcache = CMemcache(self.memcaches, num_clients = num_mc_clients)
      File "/reddit/r2/r2/lib/cache.py", line 108, in __init__
        client.behaviors.update(behaviors)
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pylibmc.py", line 105, in update
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pylibmc.py", line 172, in set_behaviors
    _pylibmc.MemcachedError: memcached_behavior_set returned 45
```

I'm an absolute noob when it comes to running web services, just started learning Linux, and only know T-SQL and ActionScript 2.  So, suffice to say that I'm a bit out of my depth here.

I know there are issues with various versions of python-webhelpers, and at least libmemcached, and at this point, I'm pretty stuck.  I'm not great at Linux, so I'm never sure what version of a program I've got installed, and neither am I sure which versions are the working versions for what's in the git repository at the moment.  What I'd like to do would be to uninstall libmemcached and webhelpers, and reinstall to the correct version.  I get the feeling that doing this would require me to re-do much of the process, which is fine, provided it works.

Any help on how to resolve this error would be MUCH appreciated.  I've gotten a lot of help previously from answered questions on this site, and I'm hoping someone much smarter than me has the answer to this one!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exact same problem, and downgrading to `libmemcached-0.48` fixed it.

Make sure you rebuild `pylibmc` after you do this.